# Solve is not finding a solution for simple set of equations

Tags: equation-solving

```
Solve[ (-k1*i + k1*r == -k2*t) && (i + r == t) && (rc == 
r/i), rc, Reals]
```

is giving no solutions, i.e. `{}`.

However `rc->(k1-k2)/(k1+k2)` is a solution...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Solve[(-k1*i + k1*r == -k2*t) && (i + r == t) && (rc == r/i), rc, {i, r, t}, Reals]
{{rc -> (k1 - k2)/(k1 + k2)}}
```

Comment: So the form of `Solve` to use is `Solve[expr,vars,elims,dom]` - thanks, that is what I missed. The built-in help is only describing the `Solve[expr,vars,dom]` form...

Answer (score 3):

You have more than one variable!

```
Simplify[Solve[(-k1*i + k1*r == -k2*t) && (i + r == t) && (rc == 
 r/i), {rc , r, i}, Reals]]
(* {{rc -> (k1 - k2)/(k1 + k2), r -> ((k1 - k2) t)/(2 k1),i -> ((k1 + k2) t)/(2 k1)}}*)
```